# Is there any difference between "He won't do something" and "He wouldn't do something"?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, differences, modal-verbs

I have read somewhere that *He won't do something* means *He refused to do something* and also *He wouldn't do something* has the same meaning.

Now I'd like to know, what is the difference in usage of these two sentences?

---

I checked the book *Grammar in Use: Intermediate* again and I found my answer:

> You can use **won't** to say that somebody **refuses** to do something:
>
> *I've tried to give her advice, but she won't listen.*
>
> *The car won't start. (=the car refuses to start)*
>
> Ref: *Grammar in Use: Intermediate*, 3rd Edition,pp 40-41, Cambridge University Press, 2009.

and:

> Somebody **wouldn't do** something = he/she **refused** to do it:
>
> *I tried to warn him, but he wouldn't listen to me. (= he refused to listen)*
>
> *The car wouldn't start. (= it refused to start)*
>
> Ref: *Grammar in Use: Intermediate*, 3rd Edition,pp 68-69, Cambridge University Press, 2009.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All words and phrases and sentences have meanings in context. Those in Murphy's book are no exceptions to the rule. Examples:

> A: Where's Bob? I threw this party so that he could meet Peggy Sue.
>   B: I invited him, but **he wouldn't come**, he said, because he had something more important to do. And when I told him that Peggy Sue would be here, he said "Peggy Sue who?" I tried to convince him to come, but **he said that he would not** come.

Therefore, *he refused to come to the party*.

> A: Where's Bob? I threw this party so that he could meet Peggy Sue.
>   B: I invited him, but **he won't come**, he said, because he had something more important to do. And when I told him that Peggy Sue would be here, he said "Peggy Sue who?" I tried to convince him to come, but **he won't** come.

Therefore, *he refused to come to the party*.

As all the other comments and Bhushan Firake's answer point out, those two statements have other nuances, **depending on context**. No grammar book will be able to give you an exhaustive answer for these kinds of differences. The best thing for you to do in this case is to rewrite your question with a couple of different scenarios and ask about the specific differences they might imply. For example:

1. Bob doesn't eat vegetables. He said **he wouldn't eat them** as a child because they tasted terrible to him. He says **he won't eat them** as an adult because they have never been part of his diet. -- There's a difference in meaning here because of the different contexts provided by Bob's answers.
2. Bob refuses to participate in war. **He says he wouldn't shoot another person** because he considers it murder, even if shooting the other person prevents the other person from shooting him. He'd rather die than be a murderer. Therefore, Bob would never shoot anyone. Similarly, **He says he won't shoot another person** because he considers it murder, even if shooting the other person prevents the other person from shooting him. He'd rather die than be a murderer. Therefore, Bob would never shoot anyone. -- There's no difference in meaning here regardless of the differences in time (past, present, future). Bob simply refuses to shoot anyone for any reason because he believes that it's murder. He refused in the past, he refuses in the present, and he will refuse in the future.

If this doesn't clarify things, I'll delete the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> He wouldn't do something.

means he has not done something in the *habitual past*, or he was not in the habit of doing something.

> He refused to do something.

means he has refused to do something in the *current past*.

and clearly,

> He won't do something.

means he will not do something *in the future*.

## Edit

However, in certain contexts, *won't* can also imply that something hasn't been done in the past.  For example:

> She won't go on a date with me.

shows that, in the future, I'm unlikely to go on a date with her, but it also might imply that she's refused to go in the past. However, there's no way to know that for sure without further context, such as:

> She won't go on a date with me, even though I've asked her ten times.

but even that sentence still has implicit references to the future (namely, unless she has a change of heart, I won't be going on a date with her).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think it isn't completely true, the book `Grammar in use intermediate` says: both _He wouldn't do something_ and _He won't do something_ mean _He refused to do something_. Now, I want to know the difference in usage.

Comment: Be careful that both sentences have a _past_ meaning.

Comment: Using _refused_ in this context could suggest a bit of stubbornness, or entrenchment in certain convictions, while _wouldn't_ might imply simple laziness. If a student was lazy, I'd be more likely to say, "He wouldn't do his homework," but, if the student didn't do homework even after much berating, then I'd be more likely to use the stronger _refused to do_. Moreover, if an individual was extremely afraid of flying, to the point where they would take a bus instead, I might find "He refused to fly" to be a more colorful way of reporting it, as opposed to the more bland "He wouldn't fly."

Comment: That all said, I find the answer given by @Bhushan to be correct and adequate, particularly given the scant details provided in the original question.  For example, you listed three sentences, and asked for "the difference between the two" (which two?). Moreover, you haven't explained _why_ you're confused. There are virtually unlimited contexts where these vague sentences could be used, sometimes nearly interchangeably, and other times the wording might convey more heavy implications one way or another.

Comment: @J.R. - Thank you. but my question was about the difference between _He wouldn't do something_ and _He won't do something_. as you know `won't` and `wouldn't` have many usages and @Bhushan mentioned their first usage, but as I said both sentences have _past_ meaning and with respect to `Grammar in use intermediate` both of them mean _He refused to do something_. I think my question had enough information. however, thank you for your attention. But I didn't get my answer. (The difference between _won't_ and _wouldn't_ in the meaning of _refused_, that's my Question.)

Comment: Then I think you _did_ get a valid answer to your question – as @Bhushan explained, "I won't go swimming" means someone is refusing to go swimming in the future, while "I wouldn't go swimming" means someone refused to go swimming in the past, although _wouldn't_ and _won't_ are flexible and general enough words that there could be several reasons for that refusal (the water was too cold, I never learned how to swim, I just read about a shark attack at that beach, I didn't want my hair wet, etc.). _Wouldn't_ can also be used to say "I wouldn't recommend swimming" but that's another matter.

Comment: @J.R. - But I've read in the book `Grammar in use intermediate` _He won't go swimming_ means _He refused to go swimming_ in other word _He won't go swimming_ has a past meaning not a future one. For example I can say: `I insisted he came to the party but he won't accept.`

Comment: Then I guess it's up to you whether you want to be believe what you read here, or what you read in your book. I find nothing wrong with this answer. _He won't accept my invitation_ means _he won't come to the party_, which implies that party isn't over yet, so we're talking about the future: in other words, will he show up at the party, or not?

Comment: @yaa110: You are mistaken with the sentence "I insisted he came to the party but he won't accept." It must be as "I insisted him to come to the party but he had not accepted it."

Comment: Or, _"I insisted he come to the party but he won't accept [my invitation]"_ (if the party hasn't happened yet), or, _"I insisted he come to the party but he wouldn't accept"_ (if we are talking about a party in the past).

Comment: @J.R. Nice explanation of my answer..even when there is nothing to explain in it..

Comment: @J.R. - You know I couldn't ignore what I've read in that book. As you know the book `Grammar in use intermediat` was published by Cambridge University Press. So that there is 2 possible state: `1. The writer of the book has blundered` or `2. There is another usage for _won't_ with past meaning but it is not very common and you've not heard it`

Comment: Or, you're not quite understanding what you're reading in the book. Yes, there are other uses, like the one you've described, but you've done a piss-poor job of asking your question. "She won't go dancing with me" might imply she never has gone dancing with me, despite the fact that I've asked her several times. That usage is about the past. But that doesn't negate the validity of this answer to the question you asked. If your question was about tense, then you should have elaborated on that when you asked the question. All you asked was "what's the difference," and a difference was explained.

Comment: @J.R. - I checked my book again and I found the difference. thank you for your attention.